# How to change the endValueString for tween animations at runtime?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, dotween

I am using [DOTween pro](https://assetstore.unity.com/packages/tools/visual-scripting/dotween-pro-32416) asset from the Unity store along with the [textmeshpro](https://assetstore.unity.com/packages/essentials/beta-projects/textmesh-pro-84126). Attached is a screenshot showing my setup:

[image]

There are few collectibles in my scene; I want to be able to run the animation with a different text each time when an item is collected.

Below is my code snippet:

```
DOTweenAnimation[] animations = pickUpTexts.GetComponents<DOTweenAnimation>();
for(int i=0;i< animations.Length; i++)
{
    Debug.Log("animations " + animations[0].animationType);
    if (animations[i].animationType == DOTweenAnimationType.Text)
    {
        textAnimation = animations[i];
    }
    if (animations[i].animationType == DOTweenAnimationType.Move)
    {
        moveAnimation = animations[i];
    }
}
```

later when item is collected, I am calling this:

```
textAnimation.endValueString = "New pick up collected, blah blah";
//textAnimation.DOPlay();
textAnimation.DORestart();
```

Basically, I am trying to change the `endValueString` of an animation and re-run the animation with the new value. When a pick up is collected, I can see the `endValueString` being updated in the inspector, but the Tween is still playing(or not) with the same old value. The screenshot showing the update is shown below:
[image]

I tried changing using the Restart/Play, switched off the autokill option of the component, tried changing the loops counter in inspector, tried using `textAnimation.DORestart(true)` but nothing seems to have worked.

The solution that I have found so far is not to use the animation component as it is not re-usable and just use the following line in my script:

```
pickUpTexts.GetComponent<TextMeshProUGUI>().DOText("New pick up collected, blah blah", 1f, true).SetRelative(true)
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can't change the endValue of a DOTweenAnimation, but you can change the endValue of the tween it generates using [ChangeEndValue](http://dotween.demigiant.com/documentation.php?api=ChangeEndValue):

```
// myDOTweenAnimation indicates a reference to the DOTweenAnimation component
myTween = myDOTweenAnimation.GetTweens()[0];
myTween.ChangeEndValue("something else");
```

SIDE NOTE: I'm the developer of the tool the OP is using.

Comment: what is `myDOTweenAnimation` here?

Comment: @vipin8169 "myDOTwenAnimation" indicates a reference to the DOTweenAnimation that generates the text tween.

Comment: but how do I get the `myDOTwenAnimation` if the animation is attached to the component in inspector, but not created using the script alone?

Comment: You can store a reference to it somewhere (like as a public property/inspector-available of some object). Or if you know the gameObject (let's call it `myGameObject`) that holds the component, you can use `myGameObject.GetComponent<DOTweenAnimation>()`

Comment: ok I see, I will try and get back to you. Thank you so much for your help :)

Comment: So, I resorted to using script only as I do not want to undo all the changes I did in last 24 hours. Now I am creating the tween for the first iteration only, and then later using the same object by just changing its endvalue as you suggested: `if (pickUpTweener == null)
            pickUpTweener = pickUpTextObj.DOText(pickUptext, 2f, true);
        else
            pickUpTweener.ChangeEndValue(pickUptext, 2f, false);` Moreover `pickUpTweener.SetRelative(true);` is not working in this case.

Comment: However, it works for first 2-3 iterations and then leading to the following exception: `DG.Tweening.Plugins.StringPlugin.SetChangeValue (DG.Tweening.Core.TweenerCore`3 t) (at D:/DG/_Develop/__UNITY3_CLASSES/_Holoville/__DOTween/_DOTween.Assembly/DOTween/Plugins/StringPlugin.cs:56)`

Comment: [This answer is being discussed on meta.](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/371715/did-this-answer-require-the-op-to-disclose-affiliation)

Comment: @vipin8169 About SetRelative not working, it's because I assume you're chaining it after changing the end value. Once a tween starts its parameters are "locked", so you can change only a limited set of them. Though if you have to change the end value often, maybe it would be better to just recreate the tween. Tweens have almost zero overlay, so it's not an expensive/GC-inducing operation.

Comment: @vipin8169 About your error instead, that might be a bug and I'd like to investigate it. Could you signal it in DOTween's github repo (where you found me the first time)? I'll be traveling tomorrow but after that I'll check it out.

Answer (score 2):

Although @Demigiant's answer is correct, at version:

DOTween v1.2.335 [Release build]
DOTweenPro v1.0.178

A cast is required because it returns a Tween object which does not implement the **ChangeEndValue** method.

So to get it to work as intended you need to cast it to a **Tweener** first:

```
// myDOTweenAnimation indicates a reference to the DOTweenAnimation component
myTween = myDOTweenAnimation.GetTweens()[0];
((Tweener)myTween).ChangeEndValue("something else");
```

PS. I could not comment it because I do not have enough reputation. Once the proper answer is fixed this can be removed.